# LDAP searchFilter samAccountName from variable defined by user input ? java JNDI. DOes anybody know how to do it?

Tags: java, jndi, scenebuilder

The user input:

```
String  usersearch = UserSearchField.getText();
```

I want searchFilter to take the variable `usersearch`

```
String searchFilter ="(&(samAccountName=usersearch))"
```

But can not figure out exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your search filter is literally searching for an account name "usersearch". You need to format your string to correctly create the search filter. Try this:

```
String searchFilter = String.format("samAccountName=%s", usersearch);
```

This code will replace the `%s` with the value of `usersearch`. Additionally you don't need the `(&` because that's for when you have more than one filter and you need to apply a boolean AND operator to them. See the [JNDI search filter docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/basics/directory/filter.html) for more information.

Comment: Samuel, you can't believe how thankful i am to you now :-).

Comment: Thanks a million i could not figure out exactly how to do it it works perfectly.....